# How to have different unquote statement for mixed utf-8 formats

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have two quoted variables in python 2.6 (using urllib).

```
>>> y1
'J%C3%A9r%C3%A9my%20Toulalan'
>>> x1
'G%E9n%E9rateur'
```

Using following unquote format, I get the first one being converted correctly but not  the second one.

```
>>> print urllib.unquote(unicode(x1))
Générateur
>>> print urllib.unquote(unicode(y1))
JÃ©rÃ©my Toulalan
```

The second one works when I use

```
>>> print urllib.unquote(y1)
Jérémy Toulalan
```

I tried to use a try/exception scheme like this for y1 but It never goes to the exception part

```
try:
      st=urllib.unquote(unicode(y)).encode("utf-8")
   except:
      st=urllib.unquote(y)
  print st
```

any idea what I am doing wrong? or is there a better way to tell the difference between x1 and y1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different encodings. One uses UTF-8, the other Latin 1.

You'll have to use a `try`/`except` and hope for the best. Decode the value **after** unquoting:

```
try:
    st = urllib.unquote(y).decode('utf8')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    st = urllib.unquote(y).decode('latin1')
```

Quoted values are not Unicode strings, don't try to threat them as such. It only worked on the `x1` example by accident because the first 255 Unicode codepoints *happen* to reuse the Latin-1 standard.

If these strings are coming from one source of web data, you should try and figure out when what encoding is being used. See if there are `Content-Type` headers with a `charset` parameter, for example, that could give you a clue as to what is being used. Some Latin-1 sequences could be mistaken for UTF-8 otherwise.